# saving csv file but it no seperate per columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, multiple-columns

```
expcsv = {'PREDICTION OF' : ['CUTTING TEMPERATURE :','SURFACE ROUGHNESS :','CUTTING FORCE X :',
                                 'CUTTING FORCE Y :','CUTTING FORCE Z :'],
              'VALUE' : [out_arrct,out_arrra,out_arrfx,out_arrfy,out_arrfz],
              'METRICS' : ['°C','μm','N','N','N']
              }
    expcsvdf = pd.DataFrame(expcsv, columns=['PREDICTION OF', 'VALUE', 'METRICS'])
        
    data = [("csv file(*.csv)","*.csv")]
    file = asksaveasfilename(filetypes = data, defaultextension = data)
    with open(file,"w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(str(expcsvdf))
```

i had write columns to make it seperate on csv but it still merge in 1 column, if i am not writing str it can run well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pandas [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) utility:

```py
import pandas as pd

out_arrct, out_arrra, out_arrfx, out_arrfy, out_arrfz = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

expcsv = {'PREDICTION OF' : ['CUTTING TEMPERATURE :','SURFACE ROUGHNESS :','CUTTING FORCE X :',
                                 'CUTTING FORCE Y :','CUTTING FORCE Z :'],
              'VALUE' : [out_arrct,out_arrra,out_arrfx,out_arrfy,out_arrfz],
              'METRICS' : ['°C','μm','N','N','N']
              }

expcsvdf = pd.DataFrame(expcsv, columns=['PREDICTION OF', 'VALUE', 'METRICS'])


# now let's save those to csv:
expcsvdf.to_csv('your_filename.csv', 
    sep=',',  # char used as separator between columns
    index=False, # do not save index column
    header=True  # do save headers
)
```

let's load the file to see how is it:

```py
with open('your_filename.csv', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

the output is:

```
PREDICTION OF,VALUE,METRICS
CUTTING TEMPERATURE :,1,°C
SURFACE ROUGHNESS :,2,μm
CUTTING FORCE X :,3,N
CUTTING FORCE Y :,4,N
CUTTING FORCE Z :,5,N
```

And if you want to recover your dataframe, you just need this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_filename.csv', sep=',')
print(df)
```

where the output is:

```
           PREDICTION OF  VALUE METRICS
0  CUTTING TEMPERATURE :      1      °C
1    SURFACE ROUGHNESS :      2      μm
2      CUTTING FORCE X :      3       N
3      CUTTING FORCE Y :      4       N
4      CUTTING FORCE Z :      5       N
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, the problem is solved now, i have add asksavefilename too, and is csv had separate column

Comment: i want to ask again, if i want file not include [ value ] , can it show on csv not bring [ ]??

Comment: Sorry @AnandaJulianNugraha I didn't get your question. Do you want to remove the column `value` before saving? If that's the case, you can select which columns before saving as follows: `expcsvdf[["PREDICTION OF", METRICS"]].to_csv("your_filename.csv",...)`

Comment: Sorry @RodrigoLaguna i forgot to check notif. The problem is when is saved on csv the value write " [ 1 ] " not " 1 " i want to remove symbol [ and ]

Comment: Make sure that the values you are saving are actually integers like `1` instead of lists of integers like `[1]`.

Comment: So if the values is float it must change to integer to remove [ and ]?

Comment: Nope, the brackets are just telling that this is a list. So, you're having a list with a single element: a number (I said integers because you were using `1`, but it's the same for floats) and you want to save just the number not the list with the number. So, instead of saving `out_arrct` try with `out_arrct[0]` (assuming this is the one that causes the trouble)

Comment: ohh i see, i had try with ```out_arrct[0]``` its no more brackets again in csv file, thanks matee